# pint's usage with numpy's concatenate

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pint

I have this toy example  where I am using pint and numpy -

```
import numpy as np

from pint import UnitRegistry

ureg = UnitRegistry()

Q_ = ureg.Quantity

args = []

for k in range(0,17):
   uwnd = Q_(np.ones((1,73,144)),'meter / second')
    args.append(uwnd)
uwndTot = np.vstack(args)
print(uwndTot.shape)
for element in args:
   print(type(element))
```

The shape of uwndTot is

```
 (17,73,144)
```

As shown above the type of the element in args is

```
<class 'pint.quantity.build_quantity_class.<locals>.Quantity'>
```

But instead if I print out the type of uwndTot in the following way I get

```
 for element in uwndTot:
    print(type(element))
```

I get

```
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So I am unable to extract the units of uwnd from this procedure. Is that correct behavior ? Why does the type change when I issue the call

```
  np.vstack(args)
```

or

```
 np.concatenate(args,axis = 0)
```

I want to be able to use vstack or concatenate. Is there another way ?

**UPDATE**
 I have a bunch of netCDF files which when I read in are of shape (73,144). I need to concatenate 'n' of them which will give me a numpy array of shape
(17,73,144). Those netCDF files have units of meters / second or other units. Those units are required in my calculation.

Comment: `concatenate` doesn't know anything about `pint`.

Comment: @hpaulj - so how would I do this ? Do I just need to add to concatenate Quantity class  again ?

Comment: Have you tried using [cdo](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki) or [nco](http://research.jisao.washington.edu/data_sets/nco/) for manipulating your netcdf files? At least `cdo` also provides a [python wrapper](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki/Cdo%7Brbpy%7D).

Comment: I havent used `pint`, but a quick glance at its docs suggests the `concatenate` is in the category of `asanyarray` functions that cannot pass `pint` objects.  You probably have to concatenate, and then recreate the `pint` objects.  And you'll also want to ensure that the units are consistent within the list.

Comment: @hpaulj - I think yours is the right answer. I will have to concatenate and then recreate the pint objects.

Comment: @ThomasKühn - The question is related to pint not cdo or nco. Yes I have used both to concatenate netdf file. The next step is to add units to that array of netcdf files. That is the question here.

Comment: @gansub I understood that the question was about pint. I was just wondering whether there would be a better tool for the job. Anyway, if you found a solution, then everything is fine ;)

Comment: @ThomasKühn - oh well if you have a better solution to add units to the output of cdo/nco I will be happy to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what we use in MetPy to do this, making sure that all source arrays have compatible dimensionality:

```
def concatenate(arrs, axis=0):
    dest = 'dimensionless'
    for a in arrs:
        if hasattr(a, 'units'):
            dest = a.units
            break

    data = []
    for a in arrs:
        if hasattr(a, 'to'):
            a = a.to(dest).magnitude
        data.append(np.atleast_1d(a))

    return units.Quantity(np.concatenate(data, axis=axis), dest)
```